# Checkboxes with watchdog_severity_levels()

Tags: php, drupal, foreach, drupal-7, watchdog

I have this code that gets me out some checkboxes with the watchdog severities:

```
  /**
   * Checkbox for errors, alerts, e.t.c
   */
  foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $severity => $description) {
    $key = 'severity_errors' . $severity;
    $form['severity_errors'][$key] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('@description', array('@description' => drupal_ucfirst($description))),
      '#default_value' => variable_get($key, array()),  
    );
    return system_settings_form($form);
  }
```

I set this $key in my code as:

```
$key = array_filter(variable_get($key,array()));
```

I think this set is wrong as the drupal gets me out error.
After that set of $key I call it with the following foreach statement could someone help me with that thing?

```
foreach ($key as $value) {
  if ($value == 'warning') {
    blablblablabla....
  }
  elseif ($value == 'notice') {
    blablablbalbal....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your logic, you would store following keys `severity_errors0`, `severity_errors1`, `severity_errors2`, ... in the `variable` table because the `$severity` key of your foreach is just the index.

**Wouldn't it be easier to store an array of selected severity levels as one entry in the variable table?**

Here some example code which does the job for you:

```
// Retrieve store variable
$severity_levels = variable_get('severity_levels', array());

// Declare empty options array
$severity_options = array();

// Loop through each severity level and push to options array for form
foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $severity) {
    $severity_options[$severity] = t('@description', array(
        '@description' => drupal_ucfirst($severity),
    ));
}

// Generate checkbox list for given severity levels
$form['severity_levels'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => $severity_options,
    '#default_value' => array_values($severity_levels),
);

return system_settings_form($form);
```

Now to retrieve the selected severity levels, you do something like this:

```
// Retrieve store variable
$severity_levels = variable_get('severity_levels', array());

foreach ($severity_levels as $level => $selected) {
    if (!$selected) {
        // Severity level is not selected
        continue;
    }

    // Severity level is selected, do your logic here
    // $level
}
```

Comment: I understand your code but how i can use the severities in a if statement?e.g:  if ($levels == 'Warning' ) {

Comment: ok i found out the answer thank you very much that is what i wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some debugging to figure out where exactly it's going wrong. Would recommend using [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) to inspect the code at some of the key stages like 1) after building the form, 2) when you assign the array to $key and 3) before starting the final foreach loop so you can pinpoint where it's going wrong and address it.