# How could i use a watchdog hook?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, watchdog

I do not understand how i can use the hook_watchdog from the drupal site could anyone help me to find out how it works? I want to get the messages from the watchdog table. What is the main use of this hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hook_watchdog` gives you the possibility to route log events to emails, other databases, and more options. I recommend you to read the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7).

If you want to use it, you need to create a custom module and implements `hook_watchdog`.

However, if you want to get the messages only, you could use [Views Watchdog module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog).

Comment: thx for your answers what I really want is to take only the error messages and send it to a site.....i did it with the: $query = db_select('watchdog', 'w') // add your desired fields, conditions and order $result = $query->execute();.... But I must do this thing somehow with the watchdog...did you know what could help me? Also could you help me in this question?:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896332/plz-check-this-out-checkboxes-with-watchdog-severity-levels

Comment: With the module I shared you. This module provides filters you can use.

Comment: i can use this module in my module?

Comment: You have to install the module and enable it. It provides you a view with all the watchdog messages. You can add filter criteria to get what you want.

Comment: i enabled this module but i cannot find it in my site i am new in drupal sorry

Answer (score 0):

As the Drupal documentation mentions:

> This hook allows modules to route log events to custom destinations,
>   such as SMS, Email, pager, syslog, ...etc.

In other words, it allows you to intercept all entries to the watchdog table to be able to do some custom logging in your web application. For example, you could send a SMS when the application throws `WATCHDOG_EMERGENCY` exceptions.

If you want to load the message from the `watchdog` table, you could simply load the entries from the database using `db_select`

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
// add your desired fields, conditions and order

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: thx for your answers what I really want is to take only the error messages and send it to a site.....i did it with the: $query = db_select('watchdog', 'w')
// add your desired fields, conditions and order

$result = $query->execute();.... But I must do this thing somehow with the watchdog...did you know what could help me?  Also could you help me in this question?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896332/plz-check-this-out-checkboxes-with-watchdog-severity-levels

Comment: What do you mean by `send it to a site` ? You want to store the error message somewhere else ?